# Get the PID from the child process

Tags: bash, time, pid, cp

I am having an issue trying to get the PID from a command using Time. 
The command I use is:

```
{ time cp  ubuntu/ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso 
 ubuntucopia/$i-ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso; } 
    2>> "logs/time.log" &
```

If I use now `$!`, I've get te PID from TIME. How could I do to get the pid of the command `cp`? Currently to solve this I am using this:

```
father=$!           
cpPid=$(pgrep -P $father)
```

With this, not always I get the pid, sometimes $cpPid is empty.

Thank you!

Comment: `time` is a shell builtin command and it cannot have a PID.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the pid of the cp command, though you should use a search string more specific than cp, as this sample has a high potential for multiple matches.

```
ps -eo pid,cmd | grep cp | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Hi, ur answer results to be effective. But, as you said, it has more than 7 matches. Could you give me some way to try to solve this? I am trying to get the answer but I don't know how to determine which is the correct one.Thanks

Comment: you might expand the details from the ps command (ps aux | grep cp) and look for something uniquely identifying and consistent about the process and use that search string instead of simply "cp"